# Spring Integration - How to read a txt and print it's filename?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

My goal is keep reading a folder and print the filename when it detects a new filename within the folder.

I'm actually gonna add more features, but this is the first step I'm trying to accomplish.

Thank you.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(s -> s.file(new File('/tmp/test'))
            .patternFilter("*.txt"),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                    .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
                    ##### What do I need to do here to print the file name?
                    .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getHeaders().get(FileHeaders.FILENAME)))
```

The `FileToStringTransformer` populates such a header during transformation:

```
T result = this.transformFile(file);
        Message<?> transformedMessage = getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(result)
                .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                .setHeaderIfAbsent(FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE, file)
                .setHeaderIfAbsent(FileHeaders.FILENAME, file.getName())
                .build();
```